# Error occured when saving dataframe into mysql database

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I am trying to save pandas Dataframe to MySQL database using sqlalchemy. But I got an Operational Error like below:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'infe0' in 'field list'")
```

Code :

```
budget = pd.DataFrame(columns=['year', 'month', 'kpi', 'lob', 'factory', 'planttype', 'market', 'product', 'uom'])
engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}?charset=utf8")
budget.to_sql("report", con=engine, if_exists='replace', chunksize=1000, index=False)
```

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/abin/parry/data_processing.py", line 465, in <module>
budget.to_sql("report", con=engine, if_exists='replace', chunksize=1000, index=False)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2615, in to_sql
method=method,
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 598, in to_sql
method=method,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1406, in to_sql
raise err
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1398, in to_sql
table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 830, in insert
exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 747, in _execute_insert
conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1306, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 326, in _execute_on_connection
self, multiparams, params, execution_options
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1508, in _execute_clauseelement
cache_hit=cache_hit,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1863, in _execute_context
e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2044, in _handle_dbapi_exception
sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
raise exception
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1800, in _execute_context
cursor, statement, parameters, context
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 193, in do_executemany
rowcount = cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 179, in executemany
self._get_db().encoding,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 211, in _do_execute_many
rows += self.execute(sql + postfix)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
result = self._query(query)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
conn.query(q)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
result.read()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
packet.raise_for_error()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
raise errorclass(errno, errval)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError)   (1054, "Unknown column 'infe0' in 'field list'")
[SQL: INSERT INTO report (year, month, kpi, lob, factory, planttype, market, product, uom, actuals) VALUES (%(year)s, %(month)s, %(kpi)s, %(lob)s, %(factory)s, %(planttype)s, %(market)s, %(product)s, %(uom)s, %(actuals)s)]
[parameters: ({'year': 2021, 'month': 'November', 'kpi': 'ry Production', 'lob': 'Dy', 'factory': 'S', 'planttype': None, 'market': None, 'product': 'D', 'uom': 'LL', 'actuals': 0.043469999999999995}, {'year': 2021, 'month': 'November', 'kpi': 'roduction', 'lob': 'Dy', 'factory': 'H', 'planttype': None, 'market': None, 'product': 'A', 'uom': 'LL', 'actuals': 10.849720000000001}, {'year': 2021, 'month': 'November', 'kpi': 'oduon', 'lob': 'lly', 'factory': 'S', 'planttype': None, 'market': None, 'product': 'EA', 'uom': 'LL', 'actuals': 4.602920000000001}, {'year': 2021, 'month': 'November', 'kpi': 'Dion', 'lob': 'D', 'factory': 'H', 'planttype': None, 'market': None, 'product': 'Et', 'uom': 'LL', 'actuals': 0.36026}, {'year': 2021, 'month': 'November', 'kpi': 'ion', 'lob': 'Dy', 'factory': 'N', 'planttype': None, 'market': None, 'product': 'avy', 'uom': 'LL', 'actuals': 3.7386}, {'year': 2021, 'month': 'November', 'kpi': 'Dtion', 'lob': 'D', 'factory': 'H', 'planttype': None, 'market': None, 'product': 'eavy', 'uom': 'LL', 'actuals': 2.7307799999999998}, {'year': 2021, 'month': 'November', 'kpi': 'uction', 'lob': 'Dis', 'factory': 'Siv', 'planttype': None, 'market': None, 'product': 'Et', 'uom': 'LL', 'actuals': 8.20483}, {'year': 2021, 'month': 'November', 'kpi': 'D Production', 'lob': 'D', 'factory': 'dd', 'planttype': None, 'market': None, 'product': 'Syrup', 'uom': 'LL', 'actuals': 24.4398}  ... displaying 10 of 1000 total bound parameter sets ...  {'year': 2020, 'month': 'February', 'kpi': 'ng Stock', 'lob': 'S', 'factory': 'Ra', 'planttype': None, 'market': None, 'product': None, 'uom': 'LMT', 'actuals': 0.48090838}, {'year': 2020, 'month': 'February', 'kpi': 'St', 'lob': 'Su', 'factory': 'cdcb', 'planttype': None, 'market': None, 'product': None, 'uom': 'cm', 'actuals': 0.6820683000000001})]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Above given is the traceback of the error.I refered the google,but could not solve the issue.

Can anyone suggests a solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Please include the structure of your table as well as the structure of your panda.  It looks like it can't find this column called ```infe0```

Comment: table structure added@ewong

Comment: Could you add the whole traceback, not just the single line?

Comment: Ok.I will add @9769953

Comment: added the traceback@9769953

Comment: Check if there is an infinity or NaN in your Pandas dataframe.

Comment: My guess is that it is related to this issue: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/246 . "infe0" can be parsed in an awkward way as "inf" + "e0", so infinity times 10^0. That is probably some string variant of infinity, written in exponential notation, that happens somewhere between Pandas, SQLAlchemy en PyMySQL. The easiest way is likely to handle and avoid infinities in the Pandas table.

Comment: I replaced NaN values with 0 using `fillna` in  dataframe.@9769953

Comment: Any infinities in your dataframe?

Comment: Then if you still get the same error, I am practically out of suggestions, I'm afraid. You could try and upgrade the various packages, if that is possible: perhaps it's an old bug that's been fixed. (I also notice you're using Python 3.6, which is past its end of life.)

Comment: Found infinities in dataframe@9769953